# How to make a popover display lists by an id that is passed from another popover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am assigned a task, but I am having difficulty in getting through passing `id` from one popover to another.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ruju/qsJ3c/109/)

**What I have is:**

a. two popovers

1. a popover with `ul li` blocks
2. another popover with colored `divs` that displays `check icon` when clicked on. This popover also has a submit button

b. whenever a colored block is clicked, `check icon` displays and its id is stored in a variable.

c. Once the submit button is clicked, `createlabel()` function is called, and it should use the switch case to display `li` in the first popover.

d. I used this id in a switch case so that a matching case would then, display `li` in the first popover.

But In my case, I am only successful in getting the id of the colored block when clicked and calling the function when `Create button` is clicked. I am unable to view the `li` blocks in the first popover.

Ex: In the second popover, if a yellow div is clicked on, The checkbox shows and id `#yellow` will be stored. The yellow is passed in switch and the matching case would display the `li` that matches the `yellow` id. thus displaying it in the first popover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be lot of issues in code. I have fixed few issues to get desired result.

Check the updated method `createLabel`

```
function createlabel(){
        var selectedColor;
    $('.colors > .fa-check').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":visible")){
         selectedColor =  $(this).closest('.colors').attr('id');
        }
    });
    $(".labellists").hide();
    console.log(selectedColor);
    switch(selectedColor)
    {
        case "green":
        $("#greenlist, #greenlist > .fa").show();
        break;
        case "yellow":
        $("#yellowlist, #yellowlist > .fa").show();
        break;
    }
}
```

Updated fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/qsJ3c/110/

Comment: this is great! But the lists disappear as soon as another is color is clicked in the second popover. I need the `li` to stay not disappear.

Comment: @vheelique remove the $(".labellists").hide(); from createLabel method

Comment: yes sir,  i had done the same but the previous list's `span` element does not display.

Comment: What is the exact behavior you are looking for ?

Comment: so i want the colors to display too. Means the `background-color` is not displaying and only the `label` displays when `Create` is clicked

Comment: yes this allows the colors to stay in the list but that is because the entire list is set to a background color. But `span` is not displaying. What I mean is how do i make everything inside the `li` show when I use  something like`$("greenlist").show()` ? Because I want the color and icon and nything tht I have inside to display. And when the next time `Create` button is clicked, the previous `li` elements or `li` itself should not disappear.